# BigQuery - using unnest with array_agg

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run some calculation over an array of aggregated data. When using a SQL function it's working:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION uniq_sum(cls array<struct<word string,word_count int64>>) AS (
  (select sum(word_count) from (select row_number() over (partition by word) r,word_count from unnest(cls)) where r=1)
);

select 
  corpus,
  uniq_sum(array_agg(struct(word,word_count))) res
  from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
  group by corpus
```

When I try to run this inline, I get an error: Aggregate function ARRAY_AGG not allowed in UNNEST.

Is it possible to run inline calculations over an array created by array_agg? 
In this case I'm trying to run some version of sum(distinct) where the distinct key is taken over some string element (so for many pairs of word,word_count I would like to run sum(word_count), and sum only one element per word).

```
select 
  corpus,
  (select sum(word_count) from (select row_number() over (partition by word) r,word_count from unnest(array_agg(struct(word,word_count))) where r=1))
  from `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
  group by corpus
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below simple query returns exactly same result as yours - so looks like you overcomplicating things

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  corpus,
  SUM(word_count) res
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
GROUP BY corpus
```

Meantime, formally, below is inline version of what you asked for

```sql
SELECT 
  corpus,
  (SELECT SUM(word_count) FROM (
    SELECT 
      word_count, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY word) r
    FROM UNNEST(cls)) 
    WHERE r=1  
  ) res
FROM (
  SELECT corpus, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(word,word_count)) cls
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare` 
  GROUP BY corpus
)
```

Happy New Year! :o)

Comment: Is it possible to write the second query without a subquery? As in - scalar subquery that is run over ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(word,word_count)), like: (select sum(x) from unnest(array_agg(STRUCT(word,word_count))) where...

Comment: Unfortunately `Aggregate function ARRAY_AGG not allowed in UNNEST`so you cannot do it in one shot